# Clean Taxonomy terms in new post type wordpress

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-meta

I created taxonomies for a post type and they work. The problem is that when I add a new post (in post type) in the front end the taxonomy terms I entered in the previous post are displayed by default. In practice, the taxonomy terms for new posts are not reset. Is there a function for this? how can i solve?

add post type

```
    if ( ! function_exists('bookmaker_post_type') ) {

// Register Custom Post Type
function bookmaker_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Bookmakers', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Bookmaker', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Bookmakers', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Bookmakers Reviews', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Bookmakers', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Bookmaker', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Bookmaker', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Bookmaker', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Bookmaker', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Bookmaker', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Bookmaker review', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'bookmaker', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'bookmaker_post_type', 0 );

}
```

Add taxonomy

```
function bookmaker_taxonomies() {
    
    // Add new taxonomy Languages, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Languages', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Language', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Languages', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Languages', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Language', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Language:', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Language', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Language', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Language', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Language Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Language', 'textdomain' ),
    );
 
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'language' ),
    );
 
    register_taxonomy( 'language', array( 'bookmaker' ), $args );
 
    unset( $args );
    unset( $labels );

add_action( 'init', 'bookmaker_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Function to display taxonomy terms in front end

```
 function get_term_list($taxonomy){
    
       $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
     
       echo '';
     
          foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     
           // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
           $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
        
            // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
           if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
               continue;
           }
     
           // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
           echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . ", ",'</a>';
    } 
    
   echo '';

   }
```

Retrieves taxonomy terms and display in front end

```
<div><?php get_term_list('language'); ?></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but I do know that calling `unset` is not a good idea, and highly unusual. Terms don't "reset" as such, can you describe your problem using different words, with examples?

Comment: I have posts for example post A post B post C. Post B and C automatically print the taxonomy terms of post A in the front end.

Comment: But they show correctly in the backend? Please update your question to include the code that displays those taxonomies on the frontend, this problem is unrelate to the `register_taxonomy` call ( also, stop calling `unset` on `$args` and `$labels` ). I assume you are using the standard post editor in WP Admin to create these posts?

Comment: yes in backend it's correct

Comment: Ah I understand now, it isn't showing the terms of post A on post B, it's just listing all the terms no matter which post they appear on

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not listing the terms from post A, it is listing **all** the terms on your site. You can test this by creating a post Z and adding new terms to Z, you will see those new terms listed on all posts, even post A.

The reason is this:

```php
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
```

`get_terms` does not get the terms on the current post, it just gets terms.

If you only want the terms the assigned to the current post, you need to use `wp_get_post_terms` instead

```php
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/

Comment: Yes now it works. I was wrong in this. Thank you!

Comment: @pasquale If this solves your problem, can you mark it as the accepted answer? It's the tick underneath the voting buttons